# PHP: Using special characters in bad word obfuscator

Tags: php, character-encoding, preg-replace-callback

I'm using this bad word detector/obfuscator in php (to be Adsense compliant). It shows the first letter of the bad word, and replaces the remaining letters with this character: ▪

It works fine, except when I'm using words that contain special characters in Spanish, for example: ñ, á, ó, etc.

This is my current code:

```
<?    
function badwords_full($string, &$bad_references) {
    static $bad_counter;
    static $bad_list;
    static $bad_list_q;
    if(!isset($bad_counter)) {
        $bad_counter = 0;
        $bad_list = badwords_list();
        $bad_list_q = array_map('preg_quote', $bad_list);
    }
    return preg_replace_callback('~('.implode('|', $bad_list_q).')~',
        function($matches) use (&$bad_counter, &$bad_references) {
            $bad_counter++;
            $bad_references[$bad_counter] = $matches[0];
            return substr($matches[0], 0, 1).str_repeat('&squf;', strlen($matches[0]) - 1);
    }, $string);
}

function badwords_list() {
    # spanish
    $es = array(
        "gallina",
        "ñoño"
    );

    # english
    $en = array(
        "chicken",
        "horse"
    );

    # join all languages
    $list = array_merge($es, $en);
    usort($list, function($a,$b) {
        return strlen($b) < strlen($b);
    });
    return $list;
}

$bad = []; //holder for bad words
```

**Test 1:**

```
echo badwords_full('Hello, you are a chicken!', $bad);
```

**Result 1:**

> Hello, you are a c▪▪▪▪▪▪! (works fine)

**Test 2:**

```
echo badwords_full('Hola en español eres un ñoño!', $bad);
```

**Result 2:**

> Hola en español eres un �▪▪▪▪▪!

Any ideas on how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: FYI: tildes are not covered by `preg_quote`. This means that your regex will break if the pattern contains a tilde other than your pattern delimiters.  You shouldn't call `preg_quote` by its string name in `array_map()` because the `preg_quote()` function does not have a default delimiter.  Adding a `u` pattern modifier seems like a smart play too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are splitting a multibyte character in half. Use [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) in place of [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

```
return mb_substr($matches[0], 0, 1).str_repeat('&squf;', strlen($matches[0]) - 1);
```

https://3v4l.org/AnPJl

You also probably want to use [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) in place of [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php).