# Why the utf8 characters are seeming like question mark?

Tags: php

I have a form in my website. I am reviewing the form values on ui panel. Function is doing if the the word length is greater than 12 it puts a space to next to it. But when I print the value I am getting error if value is utf8.

```
$text= 'üğqwoweğofkeiasş övafevpğeüqrg qğekqrğofteölzfs';

function parser($str, $parse) {
    $strlength = strlen($str);
    $counter = 0;
    $query = '';

    if($strlength > $parse) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $strlength; $i++) {
            if($str[$i] != ' ') {
                $counter++;
            }

            if($counter == $parse) {
                $query.=$str[$i];   
                $query.=' ';
                $counter = 0;
            } 

            if($counter != $parse) {
                $query.=$str[$i];
            }

            if($counter != $parse & $str[$i] == ' ') {
                $counter = 0;   
            } 
        }

        return $query;
    }
    else {
        return $str;    
    }
}

echo parser($text,12);
```

Output is:

```
'üğqwoweğo ofkeiasş övafevpğe� üqrg qğekqrğoft teölzfs'
```

and it's not happening all the times just sometimes; I can't understand why is that.

Comment: `strlen` is not multibyte safe, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52461009/php-using-special-characters-in-bad-word-obfuscator/52461057#52461057 I think

Comment: i tried the mb_strlen($text,'utf-8'); but didn't work :(

Comment: The `$str[$i]` notation is pulling single bytes as well. You need to pull the full characer

Comment: How can i take the full character :?

Comment: What should `üğqwoweğofkeiasş övafevpğeüqrg qğekqrğofteölzfs` become? `üğqwoweğofke iasş övafevpğeüqr g qğekqrğofteö lzfs`?

Comment: `üğqwoweğo ofkeiasş övafevpğe üqrg qğekqrğoft teölzf` Just without question mark

Comment: `üğqwoweğo` is 9 characters though. Why's there a space there? I was thinking something like `preg_replace('/\w{12}/u', '$0 ', $text);`

Comment: Thank you for that i think preg_replace is better for this job :)

Comment: Also parser is calculating every time -3 :?

Comment: Not sure I see the `-3` bit. I think `preg_replace` will be a cleaner approach and with the `u` modifier it will match unicode characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
function parser($string, $max_length = 12)
{
    $chars = preg_split('//u', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);


    $i = 0;

    foreach ($chars as $index => $char)
    {
             if ($char === ' ') { $i = 0; }
        else                    { $i++;   }

        if ($i >= $max_length)
        {
            $chars[$index] = $char . ' ';

            $i = 0;
        }
    }

    return implode('', $chars);
}

$result = parser('üğqwoweğofkeiasş övafevpğeüqrg qğekqrğofteölzfs');
```

result: `üğqwoweğofke iasş övafevpğeüqr g qğekqrğofteö lzfsuser`

Comment: Also adding `$parse=mb_convert_variables('utf-8', 'original encode', $parse);` to inside the parser is solving the problem i couldn't understand how it can solve that :?

Comment: When you deal with str* functions in PHP it means that you deal with bytes, not chars. It works for ASCII (English and Spanish languages) because 1 char is 1 byte, but when you try to do the same with other languages which are described with 2+ bytes per character you cut this character by half and see a � mark. Your `mb_convert_variables` is not required here, you should just understand what you do and then you'll discover how to do it.